The background color affects the mesh of the weapon!
And the skin of the mesh of the weapon comes from a Image-Texture node.




The world background isn’t just a decoration, it illuminates the scene. So, since the world background is green, you are effectively shining a green light on your object from all angles.
Since this is green, I suspect you’re trying to chroma key out the background. You can have it be transparent automatically with Properties -> Render -> Film -> Transparent. If you need it to be a video, you can then use Alpha Over in the Compositor to place the render over a green background, or just go with your current approach, fixing it as follows.
To make the background appear different than how it illuminates objects, you can use the Light Path node in the World shader, and use its Is Camera Ray output to drive a mix factor somewhere (like Mix Shader or Mix Color). When the camera is looking directly at the world background, the value will be 1, and otherwise (like in reflections) it will be 0. Have the second option of the mix node be the solid green background, and the first be something like white or an HDRI.

Thanks! I'll do that as soon as I figure out the second half of your message. You can tell I'm new to this "Blender" stuff

Sorry, I did leave it was kind of confusing. I’ll try to get a screenshot of an example node setup in the morning.
